# Website only asks to save webpage in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, internet-explorer

http://www.bumcheekcity.com

When a person looks at my site in Internet Explorer it only asks to download/save the webpage, but it works fine in other browsers. I only use Linux so am having trouble solving the issue. Is this a common issue?

Comment: http://www.bumcheekcity.com no thanks.

Comment: It's nothing to do with bums. Or cheeks. Or the city. Admittedly a somewhat poorly named website.

Comment: @AndreasChristodoulou: Aww, I was expecting bumcheeks =/

Comment: Can you add some more info? which server do you run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header returned by your server has a value of `utf-8` whereas it should look like something like this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I think this might be what causes IE to trigger a download, since it is not familiar with that content type. As far as the cause for this problem goes, it could be a million things. Try looking into your server config.